# mono - how to use ref with CreateInstance or InvokeMethod?

Tags: mono, out, ref, createinstance, invokemember

How do I pass by 'ref' using CreateInstance in Mono?

Example:

```
public MyMethod(ref SomeType data) {...
...
SomeType st = new SomeType();
object handle = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { st });
```

This works fine in my windows console application.  The problem is when I port this to Mono, I get a missing method exception stating that no 'MyMethod' was found that accepts the type 'SomeType'.

If I remove 'ref' from the constructor Mono finds the method and runs it without any issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please file a bug on (Mono Bugzilla)[https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi] stating what Mono version are you using.

Comment: Done, https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10389

Comment: Closed.  Turns out this issue was fixed after mono version 2.6 (not sure of exact version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Mono prior to version 2.6.  The fix addresses pass by ref to CreateInstance.